The existence and uniqueness of the farthest point
Picture below is from A generalized sphere theorem. $M$ is a complete connnected Riemannian manifold with $K\ge \delta >0$. I want to know how to show the red line ?
What I try: Since $K\ge \delta>0$, by Bonnet-Myers' Theorem,  $M$ is compact. So, there are $p,\overline p$ such that $d(p,\overline p)= d(M)$. But for this $p$, I can't prove the uniqueness of $\overline p$.
Assuming there are two points $\overline p_1, \overline p_2$, I feel  there should be a point $\overline p_0$ on the minimal geodesic from $\overline p_1$ to $\overline p_2$ such that $d(p,\overline p_0)>d(p, \overline p_1)$. But from Lemma 1.1 and Theorem 1.2, I fail to get it.



